# SQL Data Compare Tools that compare FileTable data

Tags: sql, synchronization, filetable

Does anybody have any recommendations for SQL Data Comparison tools that will compare and synchronize FileTable data?

So far I have looked at Visual Studio Data Comparison tool, SQL Delta and SQL Data Compare by Redgate and none of them appear to do it.

Comment: Talend, data synchonrisation tool

Comment: Thanks Rhys I will check it out

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [xSQL Data Compare](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_data_compare/?utm_source=pragmatic&utm_medium=articles&utm_campaign=xsql) to compare the tables and generate synchronization scripts. It should be able to compare and synchronize FileTables.